# How to integrate function $x^3+2y^3-6xy$ in region $x^3+2y^3-6xy=0$ (loop region)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If the function $f(x,y) = x^3+2y^3-6xy$ and we want to integrate the function in the region $x^3+2y^3-6xy=0$ in the loop region, how would we set up the double integral? The region to integrate looks like this:
[image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBrkd.png)

Comment: FYI, outside links are usually frowned upon, so please put relevant material in the text itself, and also please use LaTeX markup to make your question more readable. This will get your more help more quickly.

Comment: Could you turn it into a parametric or polar?

Comment: How would you turn it into a polar equation ? It gets to complex.

Comment: The graph is actually  ${\mathbf 2}x^3+2y^3-6xy = 0$. Check.

Answer (score 0):

$$
F(x,y) = x^3 + 2y^3-6xy 
$$
$$
\mathbb{D} : x^3+2y^3-6xy = 0 \to r=\frac{6\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^3\theta+2\sin^3\theta}
$$
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{r=\frac{6\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^3\theta+2\sin^3\theta}} F(x|_{x=r\cos\theta},y|_{y=r\sin\theta}) rdrd\theta
$$